# Haystack: save InMemoryDocumentStore and load it in retriever later to save embedding generation time

Tags: python, nlp, haystack

I am using InMemory Document Store and an Embedding retriever for the Q/A pipeline.

```
from haystack.document_stores import InMemoryDocumentStore
document_store = InMemoryDocumentStore(embedding_dim =768,use_bm25=True) 
document_store.write_documents(docs_processed)
     
from haystack.nodes import EmbeddingRetriever
retriever_model_path ='downloaded_models\local\my_local_multi-qa-mpnet-base-dot-v1'
retriever = EmbeddingRetriever(document_store=document_store,
                              embedding_model=retriever_model_path,
                              use_gpu=True)

document_store.update_embeddings(retriever=retriever)
```

As the embedding takes a while, I want to load the embeddings and later use them again in the retriever. (in rest API side). I don't want to use ElasticSearch or Faiss. How can I achieve this using In Memory Store? I tried to use Pickle, but there is no way to store the embeddings. Again, in the embedding retriever, there is no load function.

I tried to do the following:

```
with open("document_store_res.pkl", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(document_store.get_all_documents(), f)
```

And in the rest API, I am trying to load the document store :

```
def reader_retriever():
# Load the pickled model        
        with open(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR,'\downloaded_models\document_store_res.pkl'), 'rb') as f:
            document_store_new = pickle.load(f)

            retriever_model_path = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, '\downloaded_models\my_local_multi-qa-mpnet-base-dot-v1')

            retriever = EmbeddingRetriever(document_store=document_store_new,
                               embedding_model=retriever_model_path,
                               use_gpu=True)

            document_store_new.update_embeddings(retriever=retriever,
                                batch_size=100)
            farm_reader_path = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, '\downloaded_models\my_local_bert-large-uncased-whole-word-masking-squad2')

            reader = FARMReader(model_name_or_path=farm_reader_path,
                                    use_gpu=True)
            

            return reader, retriever
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `InMemoryDocumentStore`: features and limitations

From [Haystack docs](https://docs.haystack.deepset.ai/docs/document_store):

> Use the InMemoryDocumentStore, if you are just giving Haystack a
> quick try on a small sample and are working in a restricted
> environment that complicates running Elasticsearch or other databases.

- Slow retrieval on larger datasets.
- No Approximate Nearest Neighbours (ANN).
- Not recommended for production.

### Possible lightweight alternatives

To overcome the limitations of `InMemoryDocumentStore`, if you don't want to use FAISS or ElasticSearch, you could also consider adopting [Qdrant](https://haystack.deepset.ai/blog/qdrant-integration) which can run smoothly and lightly on Haystack.

### Pickling `InMemoryDocumentStore`

As you can see, I do not recommend this solution.
In any case, I would pickle the document store (which also contains the embeddings):

```
with open("document_store_res.pkl", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(document_store, f)
```

In the REST API, you can change your method as follows:

```
def reader_retriever():
# Load the pickled model        
    with open(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR,'\downloaded_models\document_store_res.pkl'), 'rb') as f:
        document_store_new = pickle.load(f)

    retriever_model_path = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, '\downloaded_models\my_local_multi-qa-mpnet-base-dot-v1')
    retriever = EmbeddingRetriever(document_store=document_store_new,
                       embedding_model=retriever_model_path,
                       use_gpu=True)

    ### DO NOT UPDATE THE EMBEDDINGS, AS THEY HAVE ALREADY BEEN CALCULATED
    
    farm_reader_path = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, '\downloaded_models\my_local_bert-large-uncased-whole-word-masking-squad2')
    reader = FARMReader(model_name_or_path=farm_reader_path,
                            use_gpu=True)
    
    return reader, retriever
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked! I don't want to use the document store as I am using confidential data. I am not sure if using the other document stores will be safe or not.